# Using Ubuntu 17.04 and Private Internet Access. I have no control of program

Tags: vpn

Yes, I am new to Ubuntu.  But I don't like windows spying on me.  I upgraded from 16.04.  My vpn (Private Internet Access) seemed to be working great.  I could see it working on the menu bar?  I updated to 17.04 hoping for something even bigger, and better.  Right now, I am trying to learn how to use this OS.  As I look at the upper right of my screen I see my drop box, the Internet connection, En for keyboard, sound, time, and the on/off button.  HOWEVER, I do not see my vpn.  I noticed in the Internet drop down box there is a vpn slot.  but, with my vpn running I can't add PIA, I can't even turn off PIA to try to reinstall it. Everything says PIA is working, but, I can't control it.  Please advise.

Comment: What is PIA? I don't know.

Comment: PIA = Private Internet Access.

Comment: I don't know enough about VPN and PIA. I have read about installing VPN using the Internet drop down box you mentioned above. It looks like you had installed PIA by some other means. Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/953419/edit) your question and add the details of how you installed and setup the VPN. If you downloaded the app from the VPN service provider mention which one and the app download URL. Then someone may be able to help you.